# Duplicated product show original description

Tags: magento-1.9, product, duplicate

I have Magento CE 1.9.2

I duplicate some product. Then edit description.
After that on page of duplicated product I see old descripion (of original product).

How can I change description of duplicated product?

Comment: Problem resolved.
When I duplicate product, all languages duplicated also. That is why I change only default description, but not language descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

When I duplicate product, all languages duplicated also. That is why I change only default description, but not language descriptions.